# Determining Strictly Concave/Convex Function

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

I have a function

$a^2 \beta  (\beta +1) (\gamma  g+1)+a \left(-\beta ^2 (\gamma +1)+\beta  \gamma  (g-1) (\gamma +\gamma  g+2)+(\gamma  g+1)^2\right)+(-\gamma -1) (\beta +\gamma +1)$

where

$0 < a <1$

$0 < g <1$

$1 < \beta$

$ 1 < \gamma$

I am trying to determine if it is strictly concave, convex or not.

Is this the correct procedure?
1) Determine Hessian
2) Determine Eigenvalues
3) if all eigenvalues positive -> strictly convex, all negative -> strictly concave, otherwise neither

I am unclear about how to pick the values with which to compute eigenvalues?

Comment: Convex with respect to what variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "pick the values"? If you're looking to find the eigenvalues of the Hessian of your variables of interest. You need to solve the equation $(H-\lambda I)v = 0$. You'll get some polynomial $C(\lambda)$ for which you must find the roots. Those are your eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't have a linear algebra background, so am trying to learn on the fly... I want to figure out if I reach a global min/max on the above function within the constraints listed above. To know if global, should I be trying to determine if strictly concave/convex wrt all variables?